# Having issues installing Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Whenever I attempt to install it, I get [this error](http://pastebin.com/pKdZwrAL).
Whenever the error is triggered, the process mt.exe also crashes. I'm not sure what causes it and I would appreciate some help. I'm on Windows 8, by the way.

Comment: You might give Anaconda a shot: http://continuum.io/downloads

Comment: @bernie How would I go about installing that in virtualenv?

Comment: Anaconda is a full Python distribution. You can create virtualenv instances within Anaconda.

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that you're currently lacking a Fortran compiler. MinGW and CygWin can both provide the necessary compilers ([see here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html#downloading-and-installing-a-compiler)), but Anaconda is by far the easier option.